# How to Properly Read from a SerialPort in .NET

Tags: c#, io, serial-port

I'm embarrassed to have to ask such a question, but I'm having a rough time figuring out how to reliably read data over a serial port with the .NET `SerialPort` class.

My first approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _port = new SerialPort
    {
        PortName = portName,
        BaudRate = 57600,
        DataBits = 8,
        Parity = Parity.None,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        RtsEnable = true,
        DtrEnable = false,
        WriteBufferSize = 2048,
        ReadBufferSize = 2048,
        ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1,
        ReadTimeout = 5000,
    };    

    _port.DataReceived += _port_DataReceived;
    _port.Open();

    // whatever
}

private void _port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{           
    var buf = new byte[_port.BytesToRead];
    var bytesRead = _port.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    _port.DiscardInBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; ++i)
    {
        // read each byte, look for start/end values, 
        // signal complete packet event if/when end is found
    }
}
```

So this has an obvious problem; I am calling `DiscardInBuffer`, so any data which came in after the event was fired is discarded, i.e., I'm dropping data.

Now, [the documentation for SerialPort.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) does not even state if it advances the current position of the stream (really?), but I have found other sources which claim that it does (which makes sense).  However, if I do not call `DiscardInBuffer` I eventually get an `RXOver` error, i.e., I'm taking too long to process each message and the buffer is overflowing.

So... I'm really not a fan of this interface.  If I have to process each buffer on a separate thread I'll do that, but that comes with its own set of problems, and I'm hoping that I am missing something as I don't have much experience with this interface.

Comment: It sounds like you need to decouple your reading from your processing. If you remove all your processing, do you get a clean read? TPL DataFlow springs to mind.

Comment: There's something *very* wrong with this question.  The odds that DicsardInBuffer() actually discards anything at all are very low.  You just emptied the receive buffer with the Read() call.  Start by turning on Handshake, that's the primary defense against overruns.  If that doesn't work (DtrEnable = false is *very* odd) then lower the Baudrate.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, I know that data is being dropped, but you may be right.  I am blindly following the direction of the manufacturer of the device.  I'll look into it.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say whether `Read()` advances the position because a serial port is not seekable -- it doesn't even *have* position.  (the buffers are FIFO too, no provision is made for random access)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sure, but the underlying stream certainly is. Of course, it buffers from the stream, so it's not straightforward. I just don't understand not specifying whether or not I am actually removing bytes from the stream.  You really need to know this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jason makes some good points about reducing UI access from the worker thread, but an even better option is to not receive the data on a worker thread in the first place.

Use `port.BaseStream.ReadAsync` to get your data, event-driven, on the thread where you want it.  I've written more about this approach at http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: Hah, I just found that article myself. I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: @Ben: You just saved my life! The BaseStream Assync-Read works like a charm!

Comment: @MeisterSchnitzel: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

To correctly handle data from a serial port you need to do a couple of things.

First, don't handle the data in your receive event. Copy the data somewhere else and do any processing on another thread. (This is true of most events - it is a bad idea to do any time-consuming processing in an event handler as it delays the caller and can introduce problems. You also need to be careful as your event is raised on a different thread to your main application)

Secondly, you can't guarantee that you will receive exactly one packet, or a complete packet when you receive data - it may come to you in small fragments.

So the upshot of this is that you should create your own buffer (big enough to hold several packets), and when you receive data, append it to your buffer. Then in another thread you can process the buffer, looking to see if you can decode a packet from it and then consume that data. You may have to skip the end of a partial packet before you find the start of a valid one. If you don't have enough data to build a full packet, then you may need to wait for a bit until more data arrives.

You shouldn't call Discard on the port - just read the data and consume it. Each time you are called, there will be another fragment of data to process. It does not remember the data from previous calls - each time your event is called, it is given a small burst of data that has arrived since you were last called. Just use the data you've been given and return.

As a last suggestion: Don't change any settings for the port unless you specifically need to for it to operate properly. So you must set the baud rate, data/stop bits and parity, but avoid trying to change properties like the Rts/Dtr, buffer sizes and read thresholds unless you have a good reason to think you know better than the author of the serial port. Most serial devices work in an industry standard manner these days, and changing these low-level options is very likely to cause trouble unless you're talking to some unusual equipment and you intimately know the hardware.

In particular setting the ReceivedBytesThreshold to 1 is probably what is causing the failure you've mentioned, because you are asking the serial port to call your event handler with only one byte at a time, 57,600 times per second - giving your event handler only 0.017 milliseconds to process each byte before you'll start to get re-entrant calls.

Comment: Handshaking should be always be configured explicitly; don't rely on the previous application leaving it in the state you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I did get a chance to test a bit last night and, like I thought, I am stalling the processing.  I can process the data on another thread no problem, but the received bytes threshold is not optional.  Like you said, I may not get complete packets each time.  Also, the packets are of variable length. My code handles this, but it means that I have to check the data each time a byte comes through. Also, a threshold of 1 does not guarantee that the event is called with only a single byte to read each time, it is simply means that it will be called as long as a single byte is received

Comment: Oh, and these settings do come from the device manufacturer. However, the advice to discard the input buffer does as well, so I am now questioning their documentation a bit.

Comment: The port will deliver data when its threshold is exceeded, its buffer is full, or when there is a lapse in transmission, so you will Rx single byte packets fine without trying to "force" the serial port using the threshold. A device manufacturer may list or even suggest a lot of detailed low level settings that aren't needed - my approach is to start simple and only add complexity when (if) you find that the default options aren't working well.

Comment: The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ...and what happens when the next burst of data is received? Does it get blocked because its data-delivery thread is busy? Or does it call your event handler re-entrantly on another thread? And how do you cope with partial packets? The answer: None of that matters if you buffer up the data and do all the heavy lifting on your own processing thread, and your event handler returns control to the caller as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

DiscardInBuffer is typically only used immediately after opening a serial port.  It is not required for standard serial port communication so you should not have it in your dataReceived handler.

Comment: That much I understand, but it doesn't answer my question.  I haven't had time to look into @HansPassants suggestions yet, but either I'm doing something inherently wrong (as he suggests) or I really am just taking too long to process a packet.